# Is this statement grammatically correct - "They'll present themselves, you'll yourself."

Tags: phrase-usage

What I'm trying to convey is that "They'll present themselves and you'll present yourself" but I feel is that albeit it improves clarity, the second usage of the word 'present' is pretty much redundant.

I have never heard of any statement being used in this fashion though.

Comment: No. It's terrible. [Gapping](https://www.google.com/search?q=gapping) only works on entire verb chains, and doesn't allow contracted auxiliaries like _you'll_ to stay behind. Also, in a sentence where so much is left out, putting in a conjunction _and_ before _you_ can show that the words following are sposta be a sentence.

Comment: @JohnLawler is right. Maybe something like "They'll present themselves and, you, yourself." Which is still not a great sentence but anything would be better than 'you'll' there.